# Ставится ли запятая, если далее идут кавычки и многоточие?

Tags: запятые, цитата

1. Следовательно, полагает автор(,) "...от факта к праву прийти нельзя".
2. Но когда русское право спасовало и не может быть применено(,) "...то для русской юридической мысли, — считает автор, — <...>" (далее цитата продолжается)
3. Наконец, "...когда конфликтная норма присваивает чужому закону <...>" (далее цитата продолжается)

Многоточие в начале цитат добавлено мной, т. к. в источнике это не начало предложения.

Если можно, оставьте ссылку на правило.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, запятые опускать не надо, но также не нужны и многоточия в начале цитат.

Почему не нужны многоточия? Если я правильно понимаю, они ставятся только *при отдельном цитировании* в случае, когда цитата начинается не с начала предложения оригинала, а не *при комбинировании слов автора с цитатами,* как у вас. Кроме того, многоточия возможны только в тех случаях, когда неполное предложение можно вполне принять за полное. У вас в случае с "то для русской" это полностью исключено.

Comment: 8.4.2. Цитаты, начинающиеся со строчной буквы
Это цитаты:
1. С опущенными первыми словами начального предложения, стоящие в середине фразы осн. текста (как после двоеточия, так и без него), начинающиеся именем нарицательным.
2. Без опущенных первых слов начального предложения, но включенные в синтаксический строй фразы осн. текста, стоящие в ее середине или конце, не после двоеточия, с первым словом не именем собственным. Напр.:
Отсюда: https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091470.html#id-8Цитаты-84Прописныеистрочныебуквывначалецитаты. Разве у меня не первый вариант?

Comment: Не поняла, зачем кавычками отделять предложение от "считает автор"? Есть же такое: «...Мое сердце превращается в камень, — безнадежно заключает Печорин, — и ничто его не разогреет снова». Тут перед и после "бзП" нет кавычек. Или это больше к косвенной речи, а у меня не она?

Comment: Да, вы правы во всём, простите! По первому пункту сам нашёл в ответе Грамоты: *Если цитата предшествует авторскому тексту, то после многоточия слово пишется с прописной буквы; если же цитата идет **после авторских слов,** то после многоточия употребляется **строчная** буква.* Сейчас поправлю ответ, спасибо!